CSS not working my Codeigniter app that is deployed on laravel forge
How can I troubleshoot and resolve the issue where the CSS is not working after deploying my CodeIgniter app on Laravel Forge? What seems to be the problem? Please tell me what you need to see to troubleshoot this.
this is the env on the forge:
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example Environment Configuration file
#
# This file can be used as a starting point for your own
# custom .env files, and contains most of the possible settings
# available in a default install.
#
# By default, all of the settings are commented out. If you want
# to override the setting, you must un-comment it by removing the '#'
# at the beginning of the line.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = production

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

app.baseURL = 'https://----------/'
# app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false

# app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
# app.sessionCookieName = 'ci_session'
# app.sessionSavePath = NULL
# app.sessionMatchIP = false
# app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 300
# app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = false

# app.cookiePrefix = ''
# app.cookieDomain = ''
# app.cookiePath = '/'
# app.cookieSecure = false
# app.cookieHTTPOnly = false
# app.cookieSameSite = 'Lax'

# app.CSRFProtection  = false
# app.CSRFTokenName   = 'csrf_test_name'
# app.CSRFCookieName  = 'csrf_cookie_name'
# app.CSRFExpire      = 7200
# app.CSRFRegenerate  = true
# app.CSRFExcludeURIs = []
# app.CSRFSameSite    = 'Lax'

# app.CSPEnabled = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

database.default.hostname = 127.0.0.1
database.default.database = palscon_rms
database.default.username = forge
database.default.password = ''
# database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi

# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONTENT SECURITY POLICY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# contentsecuritypolicy.reportOnly = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.defaultSrc = 'none'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.imageSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.base_uri = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.childSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.connectSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.fontSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.formAction = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameAncestors = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.mediaSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.objectSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.pluginTypes = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.reportURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.sandbox = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.upgradeInsecureRequests = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENCRYPTION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# encryption.key =
# encryption.driver = OpenSSL
# encryption.blockSize = 16
# encryption.digest = SHA512

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# HONEYPOT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# honeypot.hidden = 'true'
# honeypot.label = 'Fill This Field'
# honeypot.name = 'honeypot'
# honeypot.template = '<label>{label}</label><input type="text" name="{name}" value=""/>'
# honeypot.container = '<div style="display:none">{template}</div>'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# SECURITY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# security.tokenName  = 'csrf_token_name'
# security.headerName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
# security.cookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name'
# security.expires    = 7200
# security.regenerate = true
# security.redirect   = true
# security.samesite   = 'Lax'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGER
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# logger.threshold = 4


I also don't know how to setup this codeigniter project so i literally no idea where to look, start and how to fix it.
I tried fixing the file path of the css but still nothing.
